# Vb.net - FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog

I am having some troubles with `FolderBrowserDialog`
I've tried all the post I could find here and I'm almost there in terms of what I want.
following is my code:

```
Private Sub ButtonBrowseOutput_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonBrowseOutput.Click
    Dim dialog = New FolderBrowserDialog()
    dialog.SelectedPath = Application.StartupPath
    If DialogResult.OK = dialog.ShowDialog() Then
        TextBoxShowOutput.Text = dialog.ToString & "/helloforum" & ".txt"
    End If
End Sub
```

would give me something like this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog/helloforum.txt
```

Where I want it to give it for example:

```
c:/users/sexyname/desktop/helloforum.txt
```

Comment: does `helloforum.txt` always taking from your `application.startupPath` ??

Comment: yes it does for me :)

Comment: if so then you need not to use this `Dim dialog = New FolderBrowserDialog()` instead of this  you could get the file name like `textBoxShowOutput.Text = Application.StartupPath & "/helloforum.txt"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TextBoxShowOutput.Text = dialog.ToString & "/helloforum" & ".txt"
```

Must be:

```
TextBoxShowOutput.Text = dialog.SelectedPath & "/helloforum" & ".txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

SelectedPath - Gets or sets the path selected by the user.

```
dialog.SelectedPath & "/helloforum.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for your knowledge

```
Private Sub AbsolutePathOfDialogBoxes()
    Dim dlgFolder = New FolderBrowserDialog
    Dim dlgOpenFile = New OpenFileDialog
    Dim dlgSaveFile = New SaveFileDialog
    Dim absolutePath As String
    '/*-----------------------------------*/'
    absolutePath = dlgFolder.SelectedPath
    absolutePath = dlgOpenFile.FileName
    absolutePath = dlgSaveFile.FileName
    '/*-----------------------------------*/'
End Sub
```

Happy Coding