# How to work with FolderBrowserDialog in Visual Basic 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, folderbrowserdialog

I have searched all over Internet and MSDN but can't find the code to open just the FolderBrowserDialog not to be confused with Fial Dialog. I am unable to open the FolderBrowserDialog and get its value and work with it.

Many thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vb.net - FolderBrowserDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260409/vb-net-folderbrowserdialog).  See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 See also https://www.google.com/#q=folderbrowserdialog+vb.net+example

Comment: You clearly haven't looked properly because the MSDN documentation for the `FolderBrowserDialog` class includes a code example.  It should have taken about 20 seconds to find the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy , just make a project with TextBox1 and Button1 And FolderBrowserDialog1 , and this is the code for Button1 .

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
        TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    End Sub
```